# Python Tkinter publish events

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some small PyQt program that I want to convert to Tkinter(because of commercial license). And I wonder how easy was working with multi-threading on Qt:

```
class DownloadFileThread(QtCore.QThread):
    download_error = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)
    download_progress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    download_finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def run(self):
        # some code here ...
        if error:
           self.download_error.emit(
                f'Error',
                f'error'
            )
        elif progress:
            self.download_progress.emit(progress)
        else:
            self.download_finished.emit()
        f.close()


# and then somewhere in GUI class:

def set_progress_bar_value(self, val):
    self.progress_bar.setValue(val)

self.download_file_thread.download_progress.connect(self.set_progress_bar_value)
```

So I have fully independent class that allows me to connect multiple widgets and control them based on `SIGNALS`

But I read a lot of articles and examples and still can't figure out how to implement something like this on Tkinter. How to make fully independent class that should post events to main thread and then GUI class should handle this events and update UI.

Comment: Qt and tkinter paradigms are very different, you cannot translate directly the logic of signals & slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the standard python thread module in python for  Tkinter and find it works great..

Here is an excerpt from a program used for streaming data from an API..

Hopefully it can give you a head start but it is pure functional based..

In my case it worked a charm.. The program crashes without..

```
def get_data():
    """Parse and dump all data."""
    fnt = font.Font(family="Courier New", size=14)
    textPad = tkinter.Frame(root)
    textPad.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    T = tkinter.Text(textPad, font=fnt, height=29)
    scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(textPad)
    .....



def thread_stuff():
    t = threading.Thread(target=get_data)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```